# Какая функция будет производительнее?

Tags: javascript, html, производительность

Функция `traversalTreeDOM`, у нее есть один +, она будет работать в более древних браузерах.

Какая функция производительнее, `traversalTreeDOM` или `traversalTree`

Конкретнее интересует:
что будет быстрее и производительнее, много раз сделать `document.createElement('');` и `.appendChild();` или один раз сделать `.innerHTML`?

```js
var tree = [
 {
  title: 'Razdel 1',
  url: 'razdel_1',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 1',
    url: 'razdel_1_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 2',
    url: 'razdel_1_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 3',
    url: 'razdel_1_3',
    children: [
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 1',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_1',
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 2',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_2',
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 3',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_3',
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 2',
  url: 'razdel_2',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 1',
    url: 'razdel_2_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 2',
    url: 'razdel_2_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 3',
    url: 'razdel_2_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 3',
  url: 'razdel_3',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 1',
    url: 'razdel_3_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 2',
    url: 'razdel_3_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 3',
    url: 'razdel_3_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 4',
  url: 'razdel_4',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 1',
    url: 'razdel_4_1',
    children: [
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 1',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_1'
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 2',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_2',
      children: [
       {
        title: 'Razdel 4 1 2 1',
        url: 'razdel_4_1_2_1',
       },
       {
        title: 'Razdel 4 1 2 2',
        url: 'razdel_4_1_2_2',
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 3',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_3'
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 2',
    url: 'razdel_4_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 3',
    url: 'razdel_4_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 5',
  url: 'razdel_5',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 1',
    url: 'razdel_5_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 2',
    url: 'razdel_5_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 3',
    url: 'razdel_5_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 6',
  url: 'razdel_6'
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 7',
  url: 'razdel_7',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 1',
    url: 'razdel_7_1',
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 2',
    url: 'razdel_7_2',
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 3',
    url: 'razdel_7_3',
   }
  ]
 }
];

function traversalTree(tree) {
 var rootPath = [{
  node: tree,
  counter: 0
 }];

 var html = '<ul>';

 while(rootPath.length) {
  var index = rootPath[rootPath.length - 1];
  var item = index.node[index.counter];
  if(index.counter === index.node.length) {
   rootPath.pop();
   html += '</ul>';
   if(rootPath.length) {
    html += '</li>';
   }
   continue;
  }

  html += '<li><a href="#' + item['url'] + '">' + item['title'] + '</a>';

  if(item.children) {
   rootPath.push({
    node: item.children,
    counter: 0
   });

   html += '<ul>'
  } else {
   html += '</li>';
  }
  index.counter++;
 }
 return html;
}

var endOk = traversalTree(tree);
var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
out1.innerHTML = endOk;
console.log(endOk);

function traversalTreeDOM(tree) {
 var html = document.createElement('ul');
 var rootPath = [{
  node: tree,
  nodeDOM: html,
  counter: 0
 }];

 while(rootPath.length) {
  var index = rootPath[rootPath.length - 1];
  var item = index.node[index.counter];
  var itemDOM = index.nodeDOM;
  if(index.counter === index.node.length) {
   rootPath.pop();
   continue;
  }

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '#' + item['url'];
  var text = document.createTextNode(item['title']);
  a.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(a);
  itemDOM.appendChild(li);

  if(item.children) {
   var newLVL = document.createElement('ul');
   rootPath.push({
    node: item.children,
    nodeDOM: newLVL,
    counter: 0
   });

   li.appendChild(newLVL);
  }
  index.counter++;
 }
 return html;
}
var DOMok = traversalTreeDOM(tree);
var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');
out2.appendChild(DOMok);
console.log(DOMok.outerHTML);
```

```css
#out1 {
 float: left;
}

#out2 {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="out1"></div>
  <div id="out2"></div>
  <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

-------------------------Обновление-------------------------

Выяснил, следующее:

Конкретно в данном случае `appendChild` гораздо быстрее `innerHTML`.

Но, в целом результат +- оба варианта одинаковы...

```js
function randomInteger(min, max) {
 var rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
 rand = Math.floor(rand);
 return rand;
}

var tree = [
 {
  title: 'Razdel 1',
  url: 'razdel_1',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 1',
    url: 'razdel_1_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 2',
    url: 'razdel_1_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 1 3',
    url: 'razdel_1_3',
    children: [
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 1',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_1',
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 2',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_2',
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 1 3 3',
      url: 'razdel_1_3_3',
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 2',
  url: 'razdel_2',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 1',
    url: 'razdel_2_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 2',
    url: 'razdel_2_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 2 3',
    url: 'razdel_2_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 3',
  url: 'razdel_3',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 1',
    url: 'razdel_3_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 2',
    url: 'razdel_3_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 3 3',
    url: 'razdel_3_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 4',
  url: 'razdel_4',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 1',
    url: 'razdel_4_1',
    children: [
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 1',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_1'
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 2',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_2',
      children: [
       {
        title: 'Razdel 4 1 2 1',
        url: 'razdel_4_1_2_1',
       },
       {
        title: 'Razdel 4 1 2 2',
        url: 'razdel_4_1_2_2',
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      title: 'Razdel 4 1 3',
      url: 'razdel_4_1_3'
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 2',
    url: 'razdel_4_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 4 3',
    url: 'razdel_4_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 5',
  url: 'razdel_5',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 1',
    url: 'razdel_5_1'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 2',
    url: 'razdel_5_2'
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 5 3',
    url: 'razdel_5_3'
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 6',
  url: 'razdel_6'
 },
 {
  title: 'Razdel 7',
  url: 'razdel_7',
  children: [
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 1',
    url: 'razdel_7_1',
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 2',
    url: 'razdel_7_2',
   },
   {
    title: 'Razdel 7 3',
    url: 'razdel_7_3',
   }
  ]
 }
];

console.time('GEN');
function genTree(title, url, lvl) {
 if(lvl > 10) {
  return;
 }
 var tree = [];
 var int = randomInteger(3, 5);
 for (var i = 0; i < int; i++) {
  tree[i] = {
   title: title + ' ' + (i + 1),
   url: url + '_' + (i +1)
  };
  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
   tree[i].children = genTree(title + ' ' + (i + 1), url + '_' + (i +1), lvl + 1);
  }
 }

 return tree;
}

var newTree = genTree('Razdel', 'razdel', 0);
console.timeEnd('GEN');

function traversalTree(tree) {
 var rootPath = [{
  node: tree,
  counter: 0
 }];

 var html = '<ul>';

 while(rootPath.length) {
  var index = rootPath[rootPath.length - 1];
  var item = index.node[index.counter];
  if(index.counter === index.node.length) {
   rootPath.pop();
   html += '</ul>';
   if(rootPath.length) {
    html += '</li>';
   }
   continue;
  }

  html += '<li><a href="#' + item['url'] + '">' + item['title'] + '</a>';

  if(item.children) {
   rootPath.push({
    node: item.children,
    counter: 0
   });

   html += '<ul>'
  } else {
   html += '</li>';
  }
  index.counter++;
 }
 return html;
}

var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');

console.time('ALL1');
console.time('Function #1');
var endOk = traversalTree(newTree);
console.timeEnd('Function #1');
console.time('innerHTML');
out1.innerHTML = endOk;
console.timeEnd('innerHTML');
console.timeEnd('ALL1');

function traversalTreeDOM(tree) {
 var html = document.createElement('ul');
 var rootPath = [{
  node: tree,
  counter: 0
 }];

 while(rootPath.length) {
  var index = rootPath[rootPath.length - 1];
  var item = index.node[index.counter];
  if(index.counter === index.node.length) {
   rootPath.pop();
   if(rootPath.length) {
    html = html.parentElement.parentElement;
   }
   continue;
  }

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = '#' + item['url'];
  var text = document.createTextNode(item['title']);
  a.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(a);
  html.appendChild(li);

  if(item.children) {
   var html = document.createElement('ul');
   rootPath.push({
    node: item.children,
    counter: 0
   });

   li.appendChild(html);
  }
  index.counter++;
 }
 return html;
}

var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');

console.time('ALL2');
console.time('Function #2');
var DOMok = traversalTreeDOM(newTree);
console.timeEnd('Function #2');
console.time('appendChild');
out2.appendChild(DOMok);
console.timeEnd('appendChild');
console.timeEnd('ALL2');

console.log(endOk === DOMok.outerHTML);
```

```css
#out1 {
 float: left;
}

#out2 {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="out1"></div>
  <div id="out2"></div>
  <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а зачем гадать, если можно проверить?

Comment: @ThisMan , а как?

Comment: НО `EDGE` больше нравится первый вариант... НАМНОГО БОЛЬШЕ...

Comment: Мне кажется у вас релевантны только ALL, потому как DOM строится до appendChild. В моём Я.браузер `ALL1:89, ALL2: 139`

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML медленнее из-за того, что заново рендерит весь родительский элемент.

Comment: Но разве не это и требуется? Кто сказал, что полный рендер того же DOM по частям должен быть быстрее?